# getting the alert box value in php variable & save in database

Tags: javascript, php

I am new to php. I need to get the alert box prompt value in a php variable and want to save that variable in a data base. How can I do this? Pleases some one one help me asap

Comment: How is the alert being generated? Assuming JS, you'll need to use AJAX for a seamless transition, or post the value back

Comment: No. You try then we help with any issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post the variable to a `PHP` file with [jQuery post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
$.post( "saveVariable.php", { var: variable } );
```

You have to create the `saveVariable.php` file and save the [post](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) value `$_POST['var']` in `MySQL`

If you need to know how to install jQuery see this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp)

Answer (score 2):

you can use this to alert your variable

```
echo '<script>';
echo 'alert(', var_export($my_var, true), ')';
echo '</script>';
```

to store it into MySQL use [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) and [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_insert_php.htm) tutorial. (see bottom examples)

Comment: I think you forgot to link to the tutorial...

Comment: Also a link to Ajax maybe in order.

Comment: This my coding
   function getValue(){
          var retVal = prompt("Enter your name : ", "your name here");
          //var x= alert( retVal );
       }

Comment: Can you tell me what is "'alert(', var_export($my_var, true), ')'" I coudnt get this

Comment: http://www.php.net/var_export  AND  http://www.w3resource.com/phpjs/variable/var_export.php